# What is the difference between PayPal Billing Plans&Agreements and PayPal Payflow Recurring Billing?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

First - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/

Second - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/recurring-billing/

Both are used for "subscriptions" - automated payments with intervals.

Googled, unable to find an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the differences between account types and not a  programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. For questions related to the various account types, limitations and costs contact PayPal directly. Questions about using the PayPal APIs are on topic here. Other questions are not.

Comment: 1. Billing Plans-Agreements are based off REST implementation where the method in submission is entirely different; the logic is the same as Payflow recurring billing. 
2. Payflow recurring billing uses NVP/SOAP APIs, whereas billing agreement profiles can be created and passed off to PayPal to control your frequency billing you submitted, or you can use the PNREF and create your own recurring engine. 
4. The PayPal account levels are essentially the same, however the boarding process for REST VS NVP are different and approved uniquely.